# Filter to add metadata to pandoc

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I'm trying to write a filter that adds some new metadata to a pandoc.

This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/runhaskell

import Data.Map
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.JSON
import Text.Pandoc.Walk

addName :: Meta -> Meta
addName m = Meta $ insert "Name" (MetaString "My Name") (unMeta m)

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter addName
```

I get the following error:

```
add-meta.hs:12:8: error:
    • No instance for (Walkable Meta Pandoc)
        arising from a use of ‘toJSONFilter’
    • In the expression: toJSONFilter addName
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = toJSONFilter addName
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How can I alter this so it builds correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the expanation of the messages is that the compiler can see that

```
addName :: Meta -> Meta
```

is an example of `a -> a` and that only available instance is thus

```
instance Walkable a Pandoc => ToJSONFilter (a -> a)
```

Putting `Meta` for `a`, it needs to find the presupposed `instance Walkable Meta Pandoc` somewhere, but doesn't.

The solution is plain enough: we do have it that `Walkable Pandoc Pandoc`, so we can just make a `Pandoc -> Pandoc` transformation instead. That is the most intuitive input to `toJSONFilter` anyway:

```
addName :: Pandoc -> Pandoc 
addName (Pandoc m ls) = Pandoc m' ls where
  m' = Meta (insert "Name" (MetaString "My Name") (unMeta m))

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter addName
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is very clear. I was incorrectly assuming that "Meta -> Meta" would match up with "a -> a".

Comment: @RichardParsons I don't think that assumption was incorrect, and I think this answer explicitly says that assumption is correct; why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: @DanielWagner I struggle to get the Haskell terminology correct, but I'll do my best. I could see that the function toJSONFilter required the arguments (a -> a). Since my function has the signature Meta -> Meta, and Meta is from Pandoc, I figured toJSONFilter would work on it. In actual fact, there is no instance "Walkable Meta Pandoc" and so it failed. Michael's answer explained that since there is an instance of "Walkable Pandoc Pandoc" I could alter my function to use that signature instead of Meta -> Meta.

Is that clearer now?

Comment: @RichardParsons Okay, I'm very happy! It seems I just misunderstood you, and you yourself were understanding things well. Glad to discover this.